is there a gdocs hotkey for "focus the comment thread that my caret is currently in?"
Is there a Google Docs hotkey for "focus the comment thread that my caret is currently in"?
Eg in the scene below, see my caret on the left...  if I want to add a reply to the comment that's there, without using my mouse, how can I do that?

When I tried pressing the usual hotkey for "leave comment", it made a new comment on the word I was in. Which is also fairly reasonable behavior, although personally I wish that it would only do that if I had text selected. But that would mess with other people's workflows.
Obviously any such hotkey would need to deal with multiple potential comments on a given text, but that's rare enough that I wouldn't care if it only worked for the first one or whatever.
